# Is there a way to automatically allocated structs on the heap?

Tags: c, memory, esp32

I'm working with an ESP-WROOM32D under VSCode with PlatformIO that uses the default xtensa32 toolchain.
My current project involves porting a library to this architecture and the source files in C compile just fine without any alteration.

However, at runtime I frequently have stack overflow errors or guru meditation crashes. After a bit of trial and error, I discovered that this comes from the fact that this library creates large structures on the stack like this:

```cpp
#define BITBUF_ROWS 25

typedef bitrow_t bitarray_t[BITBUF_ROWS];

/// Bit buffer.
typedef struct bitbuffer {
    uint16_t num_rows;                      // Number of active rows
    uint16_t bits_per_row[BITBUF_ROWS];     // Number of active bits per row
    uint16_t syncs_before_row[BITBUF_ROWS]; // Number of sync pulses before row
    bitarray_t bb;                          // The actual bits buffer
} bitbuffer_t;

bitbuffer_t bits = {0}; // this gets created on stack
```

I totally understand the limits of the stack on this small architecture and in my own code, I use `malloc` when such a structure is needed.

Obviously, I could go and modify that third party library to replace all implicit allocations on stack with an appropriate `malloc`/`free` pair but this has two drawbacks: First, it is tedious, and second it means I have to maintain my own copy of the library.

This is why I'm wondering if any of these is possible with this toolchain:

1. Give a parameter to the compiler to make it automatically allocate structs on heap
2. Place a `#pragma` directive right before `#including` the header files so that the compiler automatically allocates structs declared in those headers on heap
3. Add a "storage specifier" on the struct definition that makes it automatically allocated on heap
4. Add a "storage specifier" on the variable declaration that makes it automatically allocated on heap

The last one is somewhat possible by using the `static` keyword but this changes a bit the semantic of the variable. And like the third point, it has the same issue already mentioned in that it creates a change in the library that I would have to keep track every time I upgrade it.

Clearly, number one has my favors but I could not find anything obvious in the documentation.

Thanks a lot for your help on this.

Comment: I guess you're looking for `-fstack-check` and maybe  `-fconserve-stack` ?

Comment: No you can't. I'd google "esp32 increase stack size", I'm sure something will comeup.

Comment: You can set the stack size of each task in your system to however large you wish. That's the only solution which doesn't involve changing your library. You can also [monitor](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/freertos.html#_CPPv420uxTaskGetSystemStatePC12TaskStatus_tK11UBaseType_tPC8uint32_t) the tasks to see how much of their allocated stack they actually use.

Comment: Thanks, `fconserve-stack` should help a bit indeed.
As to increasing the stack size, it's not yet easily available under PlatformIO but a pull request has just been merge a few hours ago: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/pull/5173/files

With this, no more hacky patching will be required